# Loop through categories, childcategories and products in twig

Tags: php, symfony, view, twig

My table structure in my database is like this:

[image]

Some categories have a child category and some not. A product can belong to:

- Child category
- Parent Category (this category has NO child categories)

My array looks like this:

[image]

**Category A** is a parent category. **Category B - Head** is also a parent category. **Category B - Child** is a child category of **B - Head**.

Now I would like to show this array like this:

[image]

But I'm stuck on how to know if it's a category or a list of products. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The data structure doesn't look ideal for what you're trying to do. Is there a maximum number of child categories a parent category can have? For example, could there be another category under Category B? Or can an item only ever be under two categories?

Comment: @Shane, there could be another child category under Category B - Head. What structure would you suggest? ..

Comment: Can a category have both child categories as well as products or can they only have either?

Comment: @qooplmao, A category can have child categories (these categories can have products) OR products. Not both.

Comment: @nielsv I honestly don't know much about Symfony, but instead of a category simply being an array key, it could be an actual entity (depends if this is how it's set up in the backend). Then, I think it would be a bit easier to check if what you're currently looping through is/has a subcategory.

Comment: @nielsv From what I've tried out, the simplest way (using your data structure) to check if what you're currently looping through is a category or product is to determine if it's an array or not. Depending on what you're doing with the data, you could recursively loop through the array/sub-arrays until you hit something that isn't an array or the type is a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Doctrine Models (which if you're using Symfony, you should be) then all you're doing is looping through the methods on the object.

Quick and dirty example with few assumptions e.g. using @Template() annotation and standard DAOs aka EntityManager[s] as well as having getChildren() and getProducts() methods on the Category.php (AKA model/entity)

On the controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/products", name="all_products")
 * @Template()
 */
public function someAction()
{
    ...
    $categories      = $this->getCategoryManager()->findBy([]);
    ...
    return [
        'categories' => $categories
    ];
}
```

In your twig template

```
{% if categories|length > 0 %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children|length > 0 %}
        ... Here you create the HTML for nested ...
        {% else %}
            ... Here you create the HTML for Category ...
            {% for product in category.products %}
            ... Here you create the HTML for products ...
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    .... some html to handle empty categories ....
{% endif %}
```

If the HTML for nested is repeated in the HTML for flat (very likely scenario) then you can create and include a macro to spit that out for you.

This is basic, but I think it pretty much covers what you're asking if I'm understanding your question properly.

Btw, you should definitely read the docs for twig and Symfony since they have examples like these everywhere.

I'll edit this answer if you respond as appropriate. Right now you haven't posted enough information to really guide you properly but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive macro. In the macro you either print the list of products or print the list of categories and then call itself.. and so on...

```
{% macro navigation(categories, products) %}
    {% from '_macros.html.twig' import navigation %}

    {% if categories|length > 0 or products|length > 0 %}
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li>
                    {{ category.name }}
                        ({{ category.children|length }} child(ren) &amp; {{ category.products|length }} products)
                    {{ navigation(category.children, category.products) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for product in products %}
                <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

You would just use this in a template like...

```
{% from '_macros.html.twig' import navigation %}

{{ navigation(array_of_categories) }}
```

This just creates a basic set of nested unordered lists but then can be used with any HTML you want, obviously.

For a fiddle see http://twigfiddle.com/mzsq8z).

The fiddle renders as the following (twigfiddle only shows the HTLM rather than something you can use to visualize)...

[image]